# Regular expression remove dash character

Tags: regex

I have a text input that will be input like the following

```
7 - BMW 550i
```

If the user inputs this, how can i use a regular expression to remove all the content on the right of the dash character so all i am left with is the first numerical value.

I have tried this:

```
-?\\d+
```

But if like the example i gave it will get the end numbers.

Comment: i have tried this. ( -?\\d+ ) but if like the example i gave it gets the end numbers

Comment: Regular expressions are used for matching the pattern not for removing.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic What would you suggest to do what i am after?

Comment: @user667430: you do pattern matching, and then you choose one of the matched groups as a result. In some languages, it is `$1`, `$2`, in others it is different syntax - but idea is the same.

Comment: In java, assign the input to a String variable, use substring method to get the first numerical value. Regular expressions come in to role if there are some inputs which are not of the pattern which you require, then you can use regular expressions to filter them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
(\d+)\s*-
```

Use `$1` to get your result.

For example, in Perl, use this:

```
my ($number) = ($str =~ /(\d+)\s*-/);
```

RegexPlanet [Online Demo](http://fiddle.re/ftpz).